# Chrome stream sound reduced when a notification is received

Tags: google-chrome, audio, audio-streaming, slack

If I'm watching a YouTube video or i'm in a Microsoft Teams call via Chrome, then I receive a slack message, the volume on my youtube stream/Teams audio is reduced presumably to play the sound. However it takes a long time to "recover" and pump the volume back up to regular levels.

I *believe* this is a Chrome thing, not a Slack thing, but I'm not 100%. I've found [this thread](https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/4821953/my-music-audio-is-dropping-on-tabs-while-other-sounds-slack-chat-play?hl=en), which seems to present the answer is going to: `chrome://flags/#enable-audio-focus-enforcement`

However, going there Chrome takes me to an "Experiments" page, but doing a find on the page does not produce the flag in question. None of the flags on experiments page that have the phrase "audio" or "notification" seem to be the one that I'm looking for.

Is this just unconfigurable? Did this flag get moved? Can anyone help me get rid of this annoying "feature"?

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: The flag got removed, see [Issue 1146876 in chromium: chrome://flags/#enable-audio-focus-enforcement Is no longer a thing](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/flags-dev/c/tOqdprQyL2U)

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill -- It looks like this is a pretty old issue :sob: Do you have any insight? Does that mean it's a lost hope that we'll be able to configure this anytime soon? I'm not familiar with this issue log, is there something that I can do to "rattle the cage" of those working on this issue?

Comment: No idea to any of your questions, sorry.